# excel query append above row to cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I've tried the `concatenate` function but it wasn't really useful.

I'm trying to accomplish, so here's a screenshot/picture
[image]

Basically I need to be able to input data for the score, then have the cell autofill the data based on the users and their score with the corresponding tile, my confusion is how to do this if/with multiple users if they're on the same tile.

Comment: Hi, which cell should autofill itself ?

Comment: Great question!  The tiles corresponding with the totals row.  And the tile needs to be filled with the name.

Comment: How many users and how will it vary? Excel is really bad a joining strings :-) One option is with a long conditional concatenation (with all your users' scores). Another option is with a helper function - which means a bit of VBA

Comment: I'm open to anything that I can really use at my work computer (big business and don't want to get in trouble) but we have a lot of freedom.  Excel just seemed like the right one to use.  I'm open to some VBA or anything else, I'm quick to learn :)

Comment: And about 22 "players" for this

Answer (score 0):

OK... i don't know if you have a mechanism for Tile 1 knowing that it is Tile 1 etc., but what I did was to put the numbers onto another sheet in the same cells. I.e. on sheet `Tiles` cell `B18` has `1`. In this way we can just reference that cell rather than any hardcoded values in the formula...

I also decided that if there were no names with that score, then we would just want the tile name (e.g. `Tile 1`)

So these give the first part of the formula that can be written into `B18` and copied to the range `B18:F31`:

```
=IF(Tiles!B18="","",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Tiles!B18,$B$7:$H$7,0)),"Tile "&Tiles!B18,...))
```

What this is doing is:

- checking the `Tiles` sheet - if the corresponding cell is empty, then this isn't a tile and we just put `""`
- using `MATCH` to see if that score is held by any user - if it isn't found then it gives an error so the `IF(ISERROR(...))` will return just the tile name
- the `...` is where the two options come in...

**OPTION 1 - Loooong Formula**
Replace the `...` by:

```
MID(IF($B$7=Tiles!B18,", "&$B$2,"")&IF($C$7=Tiles!B18,", "&$C$2,"")&IF($D$7=Tiles!B18,", "&$D$2,"")&IF($E$7=Tiles!B18,", "&$E$2,""),3,9999)
```

...and copy the `&IF($E$7=Tiles!B18,", "&$E$2,"")` section with each needed column for your 22 players.

So the unit is "if the player's score is the same as the tile number, give me ", name" otherwise blank" and we join these with the `&` operator.
This is wrapped in a `MID(...,3,9999)` so we get rid of the ", " at the start of the first name we find (the joined `IF` statements would give e.g. ", Aaron, infinite user").

This option is a bit painful to write (and read!) but it only has to be done once and the formula can be copied and pasted...

**OPTION 2 - VBA Function and Array Formulas**

```
Public Function JOIN(rng As Variant, Optional separator = ", ") As String
  JOIN = ""
  Dim v As String
  For Each c In rng
    If IsObject(c) Then
      v = c.Text
    Else
      v = c
    End If
    If v <> "" Then
      If JOIN = "" Then
        JOIN = v
      Else
        JOIN = JOIN & separator & v
      End If
    End If
  Next c
End Function
```

This function will join either a range of cells' values, or an array of strings. Using it with an array formula (entered in Excel using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) means that we can do a conditional join...
So the `...` becomes:

```
JOIN(IF($B$7:$H$7=Tiles!B18,$B$2:$H$2,""))
```

For this, each value in the scores range `$B$7:$H$7` will be checked against the tile number. If it doesn't match, we return "", otherwise we return the corresponding name (in range `$B$2:$H$2`). This will give us an array of blanks and names which `JOIN` will join...

This option means a macro enabled workbook and using "more complex" array formulas. But array formulas are great, and I advise everyone to play with them ;-). cpearson has a good intro: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx

Have fun!